# SSRS report parameter grayed out when running from snapshot

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, reportbuilder3.0

I am running SSRS 2008 R2.  I have a report with a parameter that allows the user to type in a text value.  I have the report setup to run on a snapshot, so it required me to enter a default parameter for snapshot purposes.  When I run the report, it is correctly generated based upon the default parameter I supplied.

The problem is that after the report is generated based upon the snapshot and default parameter, I want to be able to change the parameter to a different value then re-run the report.  However, the parameter is grayed out so I cannot change it.  Is there a way around this?

Comment: Make sure you didn't set anything in Available Values.

Comment: I did not.  No available values are set.  The parameter is a free text field.